# How to get rid of Origin while still playing games that require it?

Tags: origin

Is there a way to play games that require Origin without allowing it to scan my computer?

The idea is to have it running as a dedicated user on my computer which does not have any permissions so it cannot scan my hard drive.  Can this work?

Comment: Raise awareness: http://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/comments/js51f/ea_origin_spyware_issue_silently_boycotting_will/

Comment: Origin isn't spyware. If you want to remove it, simply uninstall it.

Comment: @whoever downvoted: care to explain?

Comment: As I stated below: "I believe that if a program scans my computer, gathers information about it and sends it to a remote server it IS a spyware."

Comment: @edem that's nice but, well, stating that doesn't add anything useful to the question. Just ask how to uninstall / sandbox the software and leave the fluff like that for comments if anyone happens to ask you why you want to do so.

Comment: @edem I'm afraid that just because you believe something, doesn't make it true. EA provide instructions on removing Origin on their support website.

Comment: Provide a link then.

Comment: @edem: it's already been posted in an answer, but http://help.ea.com/article/manually-uninstalling-origin

Comment: One other thing you could look at doing is using [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) for restricting what Origin could do to your computer.  You can specify what paths the program does and doesn't have access to.

Comment: Close Voters: How exactly is this off-topic?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Origin is EA's answer to Steam - that is, it's an integrated store and gaming platform, with social bells and whistles thrown in because why not.

Just like Steam, it's rather deeply integrated into some games (most big EA titles from here on, it seems, such as the upcoming Mass Effect 3) which means you can't just get rid of it. It's required to play some of their games, just as Steam was (and is) required to play Half-Life 2, the first flagship title that Valve used to promote Steam, amongst others.

I haven't seen any information on playing Origin games without it installed, apart from one hack for Battlefield 3 (which could easily result in permanent bans as it's against their agreement).

As you also asked for a link to removal instructions in your comment above, you can either use the normal *Add/Remove Programs* menu from the Control Panel, or have a look [at this EA page](http://help.ea.com/article/manually-uninstalling-origin) for manual uninstallation instructions. Do note the Scary Red Text saying:

> NOTE: If you remove Origin, you will lose accessibility and playability to any downloaded games and manuals until you reinstall Origin.

So this will **not** let you play your games without Origin.

Answer (score 5):

Origin is not a spyware program. It is a games platform like Steam.

It should show up in the add/remove programs list, via control panel.

It generally needs to be running for EA games. as it updates your games on the fly, using the internet. I dont recommend removing it, unless you intend to also uninstall your EA games. (i.e you no longer play them).

**Simple un-install instructions:**

1. Click the start button at the bottom left hand corner of your screen.
2. Click "Control Panel." Open up the "Add or Remove Programs" in the window.
3. Scroll down the current installed program list and find Origin.
4. Click Origin and click remove button
5. A window will pop up, and you can now click on, "Uninstall." .
6. Wait for a minute while your computer removes the Origin and the files.

Comment: I believe that if a program scans my computer, gathers information about it and sends it to a remote server it IS a spyware.

Comment: I can see your point of view. If it does indeed scan and gather info, it wont be of malicious intent. (though still violates privacy - You will have agreed to this on install of one of your games/Origin). I personally dislike Origin, and only use it because bf3 is not on Steam. :( Spyware is usually installed against your will and/or unknowing. with intent to cause harm. Uninstalling programs like this that are not necessary is a good idea. But it is needed for your EA games.

Answer (score 2):

For instructions how to remove Origin (and associated games) entirely from your system, check this link:

[Manually Uninstalling Origin](http://help.ea.com/article/manually-uninstalling-origin)

It may be possible to apply only part of this guide to remove Origin but not the already installed games, but I'm afraid I don't know the specifics. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin_(content_delivery)#Origin_client) hints at this but has no source for it.

If you manage that, however, there will still be no legitimate way to actually **install** new EA games without using the Origin client.

Answer (score 2):

If you think that the Origin client is eating ur pc-time or resources and/or doing other stuff, try starting the game you want and then CTRL+ALT+DEL to the manager.
Then end the Origin exe...if ur game keeps playing you'll have removed it's resource use and/or it's scanning or whatever..
I do that with all other stuff that runs when I need the extra power..

Maybe it'll help, maybe not..but good luck anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Start the game, CTRL+ALT+DEL, load Task Manager, and close Origin.

Answer (score -2):

There is no possibility to get rid of Origin. The only way would be not playing EA games - every new EA game needs origin except Star Wars the Old Republic (which requires an EA/Origin account, but does not require the Origin application).